# How to get Caja to work with Samba share?

Tags: linux-mint, samba

So I'm trying to get Caja to work with a Samba share on another computer.  This is what I have so far.

I've enabled SMB access to Caja

```
sudo apt-get install caja-share
```

I haven't been able to access the samba shared drive yet.

Comment: sudo apt install gvfs-backends

Comment: On Redhat/Fedora: `# dnf install gvfs-smb`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here goes, I need to install samba on the another computer.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install samba
```

Next add a samba user to the samba computer.  This adds a user.

```
sudo smbpasswd -a comp1
```

Then enable the new user.

```
sudo smbpasswd -e comp1
```

Now you want to edit your samba configuration to enable Caja access.

```
sudo gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf

[global]
admin users = comp1
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
unix charset = UTF-8 
server min protocol = NT1
ntlm auth = yes
client min protocol = NT1
client max protocol = SMB3
case sensitive = no
bind interfaces only = yes
```

Next edit the shared folder settings in the configuration.

```
[share]
path = /path/to/shared/folder
available = yes
#valid users = comp1
read only = yes
writeable = no
hosts allow = 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.3
hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0
public = yes
browseable = yes
```

Finally restart Samba to have the changes take effect.

```
sudo systemctl restart smbd nmbd
```

You may have to allow Samba to work through your firewall.

```
sudo ufw allow samba
```

Once that's done, in your Caja browse the Network to find your shared drives.  It should be accessible now.